# regex + np++ + capturing string at top of page and string from bottom of page

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here is my [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ItluIW/1)

What I want to do is be able to capture the Table and the page number. Example output or what I want is below. The Table part I want is hopefully obvious. The page number is `10` in `10 4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics`(the first number) and `12` in `4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 12`(the lastnumber).

In np++ I can get all the Tables with `Table \d+` But I also want the page number from the bottome of the same page.

What I have:

```
Table 1: bifrost

<lots of randon text >

10 4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 

<lots of randon text >

4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 11

Table 2: homestead

<lots of randon text >

4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 12

<lots of randon text >

12 4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 


Table 3: homestead

<lots of randon text >

12 4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics
```

What I want:

```
Table 1: bifrost
10 4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 
Table 2: homestead
4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics 12
Table 3: homestead
12 4 Text Core statistics aggregated by the Statistics
```

### EDIT1

in relation to the possible answer below, if this helps:

`(Table \d*).*?(?=\d+\s(\d+\s)?Text Core)([^\n]+)(.*?(?=^Table \d+|\z))` -- does not find anything 
`(Table \d*).*` - works finds the `Table` line 
`(Table \d*)` - workds finds the `Table` and number part of the line (e.g. `Table 1`)

`.*?(?=\d+\s(\d+\s)?Text Core)` - works finds the numbers at the start of the lines that start with a number(^zero length match) 
`(?=\d+\s(\d+\s)?Text Core)` - works finds the numbers at the start of the lines that start with a number(^zero length match) 
`([^\n]+)` - works finds lines with text(that is it highlights all the text) 
`(.*?(?=^Table \d+|\z))` - works this finds the start of the line with Table at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** actually downloaded notepad++ and tested the regex.

This will work:

```
(^Table \d+).*?(?=\d+\s(\d+\s)?Text Core)([^\n]+)(.*?(?=^Table \d+|\z))
```

It uses a positive lookahead to search for the first page number after the Table number and then grabs everything from there to end of line. Then it grabs everything Up to the next 'Table'. Note that you need to check the `. matches newline` box.

If you want to do a substitute, replace this with `\1\n\3\n`. [Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lF0fI1/277)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was working from OPs original demo example which has named groups. But perhaps I didn't understand the question correctly in terms of desired action.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Have edited post to hopefully make it more useful.

Comment: tks. I did a search in np++ on those 3 searches on my data(the data in the regex) and it says `can't find the text`. whereas if I do a find on `(?<name>Table \d*: \w+)` I can find the Table line/text at least. what am I doing wrong

Comment: Have actually downloaded notepad++ (latest version, v7.5.6) and tested this. Found a couple of issues but it is definitely working for me now. Also updated demo on regex101.

Comment: tks nick. I just could not get that to work. using np++  v7.5.4, but don't think that would make a difference. tks tho.

Comment: Yeah I can't imagine 7.5.4 and 7.5.6 are that different from each other. Have you tried just doing a Find? does that match anything?

Comment: see edit1 in the Q, I have tried to answer that. I have tried find on certain parts of the serach string. tks

Comment: Are you sure you have checked the `. matches newline` box (next to the Regexp radio button)? If you have the regex `(Table \d*).*` should match the entire document,  not just the line that starts with Table. Otherwise I am baffled...

Comment: Ah sorry, that was it. i am sure I did try that before but hey. tks again.

Comment: So does this regex now solve the problem completely? Note I made a slight edit to make it a bit more robust. If so you can change the accepted answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Apologies. Although your regex is a lot simpler, this one does exactly what OP asked for. But I will refrain from asking in the future, you are right, it should be OPs decision. Again, apologies for violating site etiquette.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer at least a partial solution.  Do a replacement on the following pattern:

```
^(?!Table)(?!\d+ (?:\d+ )?Text Core).*$
```

and replace this with empty string.  This should remove all the random text in between the lines which start with `Table` or contain `Text Core`.  Here is a working demo:

### Demo

Comment: `.*(?!Table \d+: \w+).*` I tried this negative lookahead but it is deleting the line I want to keep e.g. `Table....`

Comment: @HattrickNZ Obviously that won't work, because you put `.*` in the front.  By the way, if your actual data is something other than what you posted in your question, now would be a good time to say something.

Comment: tks, I got that to work, I then just used sed to delete all the blank lines.